# to trap event of lost focus between rows in QTableWidget of PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I am using QTableWidget of PyQt5. Table has multiple rows and columns. I want to trap the signal when focus is moved from one row to another row.

Comment: What do you mean by the change of focus?

Comment: suppose current row number is 1. If I click on row number 2, focus changes to row number 2

Comment: Do you want a signal that tells you when a row is selected or clicked?

Comment: I want a signal that tells me when row number is changed by up arrow or down arrow (not selected or clicked)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class CustomTableWidget(QTableWidget) to overload the PaintEvent and emit a signal.
In the class where CustomTableWidget is instantiated,
connect this signal to a function containing :

```
selected = your_qtable_wdg.selectedIndexes()

list_row_selected = list(set(s.row() for s in selected))
```

you can make a diff with an attribute self.list_row_selected